# How to figure out my dump_binary_path in my device? Using spatie laravel-backup package for Laravel 9

Tags: php, mysql, database-backups, mysql-backup, laravel-backup

I'm currently using the spatie laravel-backup for backup my database.

But when I execute the command

```
php artisan backup:run
```

I get this error :

> Backup failed because The dump process failed with exitcode 1 : General error : The system cannot find the path specified.

After my research, I tried to change my dump_binary_path to 'D:\xampp\mysql\backup\mysql' but it still not working. Therefore I'm thinking that I might have entered the wrong path .. is there a way to find the path?

Here is my code in config/database.php

```
   'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'dump' => [
                'dump_binary_path' => 'D:\xampp\mysql\bin',
                'use_single_transaction',
                'timeout' => 60 * 5, // 5 minute timeout
            
               
            ],
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],         
       ],
```

Any answer and suggestion are higher appreciated

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem. But I solve it from this step. you can also try.
follow this step
https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-backup/v5/installation-and-setup#dumping-the-database
then add

```
'dump' => [
        'dump_binary_path' => 'F:\xampp\mysql\bin',
      ],
```

Then click your comment link.