# How to backup Mysql Database in Laravel

Tags: mysql, database-backups

I'm currently using the PHP language laravel framework for my project, and there is a backup and restore in my feature and functions. for this, I have been trying to use spatial/laravel-backup .. but seems like it was not compatible with Windows. because it always shows up the error of

```
"Backup failed because: The dump process failed with exitcode 1 : General error: The system cannot find the path specified."
```

I believe the path is correct and I have tried to add it to the environment variance but still not working It was stated on the requirement of the spatie document that

```
“ It's not compatible with Windows servers.”
```

Can someone suggest to me a different way how to create a backup and restore for MySQL database In laravel?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72816162/how-to-figure-out-my-dump-binary-path-in-my-device-using-spatie-laravel-backup?fbclid=IwAR3KNg9Z8rYMse4m3BBWH62l5PNwSb67gJ0S-8pTj9bxWajdp-l9Lo8N3RQ

For the details of my errors , or can somebody help me to figure out the problem?

Comment: Use mysqldump -u username -p dbname > filename. sql  it works with windows, and you could make a programed task or even a custom command in Laravel

Comment: @ManuelGlez Thanks for the reply, could you provide an example, I don't understand much about it. sorry I'm just new in programming

Comment: Just open a terminal in windows and run that command change username and dbname for your real user an mysql database filename.sql will be a complete dump of your dbanme

Comment: Tip: [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) makes this a lot easier.

Comment: @ManuelGlez i have try to put the code to the terminal and its now asking for the password. but i didn't set any password for the database, what should I input?

Comment: Nothing, hit enter.